# Trouble understanding how the indices of a series are determined

Tags: pandas, series

[Trouble understanding how the indices of a series are determined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVdy8.png)

So I have a huge data frame that i am reading a single column from, and I need to choose 100 unique values from this column. I think that what I did resulted in 100 unique values but I'm confused about the indexing of the resulting series. I looked at the indices of the data frame and they did not correspond to the value associated with the same indices of the series. I would like this to be the case, that is I want the indices of the resulting series to be the same as the indices of the data frame from which I am reading the column from. Would someone be able to explain to me how the resulting indices were determined here?

Answer (score 0):

The indices of the sample **do not** correspond to the indices that exist in the DataFrame. This is due to the following fact:

When doing `CSsq.unique()` you are in fact getting back a np.ndarray (check the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)). An array does not have any indices. But, you are passing this to the `pd.Series` constructor and as a result, a new Series is created, which in fact has indexing (starting from 0 up to n-1, where n is the size of the Series). This, of course, has nothing to do with the DataFrame indices, because you have firstly isolated the unique values.

See the example below for a hypothetical Series called `s`:

```py
s

0    100
1    100
2    100
3    200
4    250
5    300
6    300
```

Let's isolate the unique occurences:

```py
s.unique()

# [100, 200, 250, 300]
```

And now let's feed this to the `pd.Series` constructor:

```py
pd.Series(s.unique())

0    100
1    200
2    250
3    300
```

As you can see this Series was generated from an array and its indices have nothing to do with the initial indices!

Now, if you take a random sample out of this Series, you'll get values with indices that correspond to this new Series object!

If you'd like to get a sample with indices that are derived from the DataFrame try something like this:

```py
CSsq.drop_duplicates().sample(100)
```